# Turn off PropertyChanged Event whilst objects are being populated by a RawSQLQuery

Tags: entity-framework, inotifypropertychanged, xaf

In my XAF Winforms project, I am using the following to populate my non persistent System.Data.Entity objects

```
  // using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSQLQuery
  List<myentity> results = connect.Database.SqlQuery<myentity>(sql).ToList();
```

myentity implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged

with properties like

```
    private string _description;

    public string Description
    {
        get => _description;
        set
        {
            if (_description == value) return;
            _description = value;

            OnPropertyChanged(); // I don't want this called when loading
        }
    }
```

I don't want the OnPropertyChanges to be called when the objects are initially populated

How can I prevent that? i.e how can MyEntity "know" that the description is being set by the initial load rather than a user's change?

I was considering that _description would be null on loading ... however it could be null for other reasons.

Comment: You could set the backing property on initial loading

Comment: That's the answer. Care to write it up?.  Only because It is using XAF I also realised I chould check whether objectspace was null.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the backing property without calling the setter of `Description`, you can set `_description` directly, effectively bypassing the `OnPropertyChanged()` call.

Comment: oh dear, I was wrong telling you this is the answer. SQLQuery sets the public property. You are right about setting a property at loading.. for example creating an IsLoading property and setting it to true in the initialize.

Comment: It does, if it is bound to the context's model. I would assume you call OnPropertyChanged() only on ViewModel properties, not on your POCO's.

Comment: SqlQuery sets the public properties.

Answer (score 0):

Create a public IsLoading property and set it to true in the myentity initializer
Then turn it off after populating the collection

```
List<myentity> results = connect.Database.SqlQuery<myentity>(sql).ToList();
for each ( var obj in results) {  obj.IsLoading = false}
```

Modify OnPropertyChanged so that PropertyChanged does not fire when loading.

```
private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if (PropertyChanged == null) return;
    if (IsLoading) return;
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```